# System.Random in ViewBag not displaying as string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, random, viewbag

All I am trying to do is create a random number in the Controller and pass it to the View. However when I run the application the View only displays 'System.Random' not a generated value.

Here is my controller:

```
    // GET: /Products/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Random randomID = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
        randomID.Next(20, 5000);

        ViewBag.random = randomID.ToString();

        ViewData["random"] = randomID.ToString();

        TempData["random"] = randomID.ToString();

        return View();
    }
```

I tried the ViewBag, ViewData, and TempData and they all display 'System.Random.'

Here is my View:

```
@model application.Models.Product

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Product";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product_ID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product_ID, new { @readonly = "readonly" })

            @Html.TextBox("random", (string)@ViewBag.random, new { @readonly = true })

            @ViewBag.random

            @ViewData["random"]

            @TempData["random"]

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product_ID)
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm sorry the View is a little messy but I tried all the approaches I could find. What am I missing? I really don't want to have the change the Model. I tried Googling this for hours and nothing can solve my problem. Also is this the simplest approach to creating a random ID number for a product? Any help would be appreciated THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

randomId.Next() returns an integer, you need something more like this:

```
// GET: /Products/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    Random randomID = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
    int randomNumber = randomID.Next(20, 5000);

    ViewBag.random = randomNumber.ToString();

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Random.Next` actually *returns* a value, and doesn't mutate the `Random` object at all. Simply calling `ToString` on a `Random` object will always return "System.Random" (as it will for every other class that doesn't override `ToString`.

You need to put the generated *value* in the ViewBag:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Random random = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
        int randomID = random.Next(20, 5000);

        ViewBag.random = randomID.ToString();   
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you BradleyDotNET I had to choose @scott answer as he was first but I really appreciate your explanation!